# "Make" error while upgrading to ruby 1.9.3-p374

Tags: ruby, makefile, version, upgrade, ruby-1.9.3

**Problem:**

I a newbie to rails and was trying to get started with rails tutorials. While upgrading to a different version of ruby, I get the following error while trying to upgrade my ruby version from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3-p374

**Error**

```
Error running 'make', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

**Brew List**

```
apple-gcc42 
cmake       
libksba     
libyaml     
readline
autoconf    
curl        
libtool     
make        
sqlite
automake    
git     
libxml2     
openssl
bash        
libgpg-error    
libxslt     
pkg-config
```

**GCC version**

```
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**cpp path**

```
/usr/bin/cpp
```

**Steps I followed**

1. Installed the XCode command line tools
2. [Re- installed stable version of RVM](https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
3. brew update
4. brew tap homebrew/dupes
5. brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
6. rvm pkg install openssl
7. brew install libksba
8. Followed all the instructions on moncef [article](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)

Comment: What does your make.log have to say?